# C# Generics - Return a List with a Type Dependent of Parameter.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Full disclosure, I do not fully understand generics but am hoping the answer to this question will clear things up.

I have an application that allows a user to build a query of their own. The query will leverage the Entity Framework. I would like to return a list of the results whose type is dependent upon what column they queried. In other words i need a method that could have multiple return types. I derive the type using reflection on the column and then would like to pass to this method.

```
    public static T getValues<T>(string ColName, Type type)
    {
        var result = db.AC_PROPERTY.Select(ColName);

        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            //Query and add results to list. 
            return list;

        }

        if (type == typeof(double?) || type == typeof(double))
        {
            List<double> list = new List<double>();
            //Query and add results to list. 
            return list;

        }

        if (type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(int?))
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            //Query and add results to list. 
            return list;
        }

        if (type == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
            //Query and add results to list. 
            return list;

        }
    }
```

I am getting an error stating that I cannot implicitly convert List (or the respective type) to T.

Can someone explain this and perhaps walk me through how to accomplish this.

Comment: Well you need to be returning `List<T>` for a start. However, it's not clear why you would want to do this. The `Query and add results to list` bit is really the meat of this function.

Comment: You can't use generics for this if you only know the column types at runtime.

Comment: Why not let your *callers* work with an `IQueryable<TTable>` of some sort and apply a `Select()` if they just want to retrieve a single column rather than the whole table? That would be fairly standard and not require your callers to learn *your* API to do this job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask yourself this: How are `T` and `Type type` meaningfully different? Why do you need both?

You don't.

Furthermore, while it's technically possible to check for a generic parameter's type, you should not be doing this. It's a code smell. If your method is generic, the method body should be generic as well. This includes not needing to know the exact value of T.

**1. Get rid of `Type type`**

```
public static List<T> getValues<T>(string ColName)
{
    //...
}
```

Notice how this method would be used:

```
List<DateTime> myDateList = getValues<DateTime>("MyDateTimeColumn");
```

**2. Make the method body generic**

```
public static List<T> getValues<T>(string ColName)
{
    List<T> myReturnList = new List<T>();
    var selectedColumnValues = db.AC_PROPERTY.Select(ColName);

    //Query and add results to list. 

    return myReturnList;
}
```

Looks a lot neater, doesn't it? I noticed you omitted the actual creating of the list; so I omitted it too for now.

---

I could get into the rest of the method body based on some assumptions, but there's a much more relevant consideration here.

**Your method seems to be no different from [LINQ's Select() method](https://blog.udemy.com/linq-select/)!**

So instead of doing this with your custom built `getValues<T>` method:

```
List<DateTime> myDateList = getValues<DateTime>("MyDateTimeColumn");
```

You can use the existing LINQ method:

```
List<DateTime> myDateList = myDataList.Select(item => item.MyDateTimeProperty).ToList();
```

(Note: `ToList()` can be optional but is advisable due to lazy evaluation).